# Alignment problem for enumerate within theorem with item of multiple lines

Tags: enumerate, alignment

I'm a new TeX user and I met a problem recently when I was using an `\enumerate` environment inside my theorem environment. If an item extends to a second line or more, how can I remove the blank on the left while not affecting the position of the labels? (That can't be done by simply adjusting the `leftmargin` parameter, since it affects the labels.) [image: How to remove the blank at the pointed area?] Or, how can I align all lines of texts to the label in the left, as the red line in the following picture positioned? [image: How can I align the texts to the red line?]
In addition, I've already tried `\leavevmode`, as advised in other questions, but that's not what I want.

Code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}

\begin{document}
    \section{A title here}
    \begin{thm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Long sentence. Really long sentence. Really really long sentence. Really.
            \item Sentence presented here for comparison. creativity bull car nonsense filter choke smug
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}
\end{document)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a minimal  code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Try to add `\leavevmode` after `\begin{thm}`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you want? I thought that in the context of theorem, the enumeration looks better in upshape. If you want only the parentheses upshape, use `label=$(\roman*)$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

    \section{A title here}

    \begin{thm}
        \begin{enumerate}[font=\upshape, wide=0pt, labelsep=-0.3em, leftmargin =*]
            \item Long sentence. Really long sentence. Really really long sentence. Really.
            \item Sentence presented here for comparison. creativity bull car nonsense filter choke smug – Fiddle dee dee!
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}

\end{docum
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code and find it perfect! But I found one problem, that is, if I place the `wide` parameter after `leftmargin`, it would act differently and could solve my problem properly without  adjusting `labelsep`.